# how to upload multiple files with php to a 000webhost server?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm making a simple site using html and php, this site is suposed to let me upload several files at the same time (Selecting them at once in the upload window which opens when I click on a 'select' button), my page already let me upload one file at once, my code is:

HTML:

```
<form action="php/cargaxml.php" method="POST" role="form" class="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name = "test" class = "file">
     <input type="submit" value="Carga de archivos" id="boton" class = "btn btn-success btn-lg">
</form>
```

cargaxml.php:

```
<?php
   $target_path = "/public_html/uploads/carga";
   copy($_FILES['test']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
   echo "File successfully uploaded!";
?>
```

When I want to upload a file I click on the button:

[Upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqhwn.jpg)

and the browser shows a window to select a file:

[Upload window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLeQq.jpg)

but when I use ctrl+click to select several files it just unselect the previous file and let me use only one file, other way I've thought is to select a folder which contains several files and upload them in a massive way, but when I select a folder and click on open it just open the folder and doesn't let me to 'upload' the folder.

How can I do to select several files to upload? My site is hosted on 000webhost.com.

I apologise for my English (Isn't so well), thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5 you can set the multiple attribute on . This works in browsers supporting HTML5.

```
<input type="file" name="test" multiple=""/>
```

For more Information in upload via Ajax https://www.creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/